# How to export 100 Oracle schemas to dump files

Tags: database, oracle11g, database-administration

We have about 100 Oracle schemas which should be exported to dump files. I'm not an Oracle expert and our DBA's doesn't seem to be very interested in helping this, or they don't know how to do it easily enough. This might be my naive thinking, but I would assume that this should be pretty easy (or at least possible) to script. Am I totally wrong or can someone maybe point me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export using expdp multiple schemas using this line:

```
expdp schemas=SCOTT,SH directory=YOUR_DIRECTORY dumpfile=schemas.dmp  
logfile = schemas.log
```

Check this example exports schemas SCOTT and SH. Before execute this command you must create the directory in your database like:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY YOUR_DIRECTORY AS 'C:\Desktop'  -- where dumpfile will be saved
```

Comment: So in this case all the schemas will be dumped in one dump file. Is it possible to create a script where every schema has it's own dump file?

Comment: As far as i know, i think it's not possible with one instruction, but you can execute the command once by schema(100 times), which is a little tedious i think.